# Does Bitcoin Core 0.21.1 support taproot?

Tags: taproot

Now the node use Bitcoin Core 0.21.1.

Answer (score 4):

When wondering if version X of software Y supports feature Z, I find it useful to search for `"release notes" Y X`

https://bitcoin.org/en/releases/0.21.1/

> ## Notable changes
>
> ### Taproot Soft Fork
>
> Included in this release are the mainnet and testnet activation parameters for the taproot soft fork (BIP341) which also adds support for schnorr signatures (BIP340) and tapscript (BIP342).
>
> If activated, these improvements will allow users of single-signature scripts, multisignature scripts, and complex contracts to all use identical-appearing commitments that enhance their privacy and the fungibility of all bitcoins. Spenders will enjoy lower fees and the ability to resolve many multisig scripts and complex contracts with the same efficiency, low fees, and large anonymity set as single-sig users. Taproot and schnorr also include efficiency improvements for full nodes such as the ability to batch signature verification. Together, the improvements lay the groundwork for future potential upgrades that may improve efficiency, privacy, and fungibility further.
>
> Activation for taproot is being managed using a variation of BIP9 versionbits called Speedy Trial (described in BIP341). Taproot’s versionbit is bit 2, and nodes will begin tracking which blocks signal support for taproot at the beginning of the first retarget period after taproot’s start date of 24 April 2021. If 90% of blocks within a 2,016-block retarget period (about two weeks) signal support for taproot prior to the first retarget period beginning after the time of 11 August 2021, the soft fork will be locked in, and taproot will then be active as of block 709632 (expected in early or mid November).
>
> Should taproot not be locked in via Speedy Trial activation, it is expected that a follow-up activation mechanism will be deployed, with changes to address the reasons the Speedy Trial method failed.
>
> **This release includes the ability to pay taproot addresses, although payments to such addresses are not secure until taproot activates. It also includes the ability to relay and mine taproot transactions after activation. Beyond those two basic capabilities, this release does not include any code that allows anyone to directly use taproot. The addition of taproot-related features to Bitcoin Core’s wallet is expected in later releases once taproot activation is assured.**
>
> All users, businesses, and miners are encouraged to upgrade to this release (or a subsequent compatible release) unless they object to activation of taproot. If taproot is locked in, then upgrading before block 709632 is highly recommended to help enforce taproot’s new rules and to avoid the unlikely case of seeing falsely confirmed transactions.
>
> ...

(my emphasis)

Sometimes I have to look at older release notes too, or other forms of documentation. But, as you can see above, this approach is fruitful.

Comment: Note that 0.21.1 does not contain any taproot *wallet* support, so it cannot construct taproot addresses or spend them. That (rudimentary) functionality was added in 22.0 and will likely be expanded to be far more user friendly in 23.0.